# Converting doc file to post script

Tags: dllimport, ghostscript, doc, postscript

I've read this blog  article "[Integrating GhostScript with C#](http://www.wibit.net/blog/integrating_ghostscript_c)" and it really helps me in my project. However, I still need to convert a word document to a post script file as the sources are made from  MS Office Word.

Please advise me if you have work around about this WITHOUT OPENING WORD and PRINTING on a FILE. Rather, use Ghostcript dll and make a wrapper code about it.

I've tried the wrapper code on converting .ps file to pdf but haven't found a code for .doc to .ps file

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define without opening word? If by that you mean no word window opens, then yeah sure its possible. But if you mean not launching the word application in the background then its quite a lot of work since you will need to reimplement word. Tough you could try open office instead :) Then there is also the question on how faithful you want it to be to how it looks in word.

Comment: Thanks. It helps @joojaa. You've answered the question so much. I think I have to look into Open Office solution. There are commercial software though as an option. They even stated that they created them on their own. Gembox is doing that (maybe reimplementing word). http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/competition